# How to wrap type around a ring?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, illustration

How I can wrap type like this?

[image]

Comment: I Have tried the  Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel and map art technique but I don't have great result

Comment: please [edit] your answer to add more information. Perhaps add a screenshot with your own result so we can help you tweak what went wrong. Check the [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I wrap text around a cylinder in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94959/how-do-i-wrap-text-around-a-cylinder-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 3):

- Draw an ellipse
- Use the **Type on a Path** tool and click on the ellipse to write your text
- Set the font size and use the **Selection Tool** to drag the *Type on a Path Handles* and move the text
- **Menu Type** > **Type on a Path** options > Choose Skew
- Duplicate the ellipse and use the Text tool to change the text
- Get the **Selection Tool** and drag the *Type on a Path Handles* to move the text to the opposite side
- Select both ellipsis and align them

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just one of a few methods....

- Set the Text: 
  [image]
- Drag the text object to the **Symbol Panel** to create a symbol
  [image]
- Draw a rectangle about half the width of the text symbol
  [image]
- Select the Rectangle and choose `Effect > 3d > Revolve`
  [image]
- Click the **Map Art** button
  [image]
- Click OK
- Adjust the angles in the 3D dialog until you are happy.
  [image]